# Download speed kbps vs mbps

Tags: internet

I have some exams coming next week and they asked for internet conectivity of minimum 512 kbps. I did a test and said i have 8.30mbps download and 11.56mbps upload. Does that mean i have 512 kbps or how do i find that out. Thank you

Comment: I presume you mean "Mbps" and "Kbps". If you really do mean "mbps", then you have a serious problem. (Also, if you mean KB/s or MB/s, those are also different units.) KB/s and Kbps are different units. Also, Mbps and mbps are different units.

Answer (score 3):

Roughly, 512kbps is 0.5mbps [sometimes the measurements are very slightly different, but not enough to matter in this instance]

That means you have 16 times the minimum required download speed.

Answer (score 1):

Your download / upload test is measured in mega bits/sec.  Your requirement is kilo bits/sec.

So you have completely adequate bandwidth capacity.  Well more than 10 - 20 times requirement.    Mega is 1000 times Kilo.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Went a bit quickly and so thanks and edited my answer

Comment: "Well more than 1000 times requirement" what??? 8m is not 1000 times bigger than 512k

Comment: I put the factor in two places - should have been just one place.  Thanks